# Find negative and positive values in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array what contains data of m/s wind speed. Both negative and positive values. Now i need to calculate the average number of the wind speed over the negative values and do the same for the positive values. Is this possible ? It's important that the data stays in the array. I had tryed something with numpy.average but without success, as he takes the average of the whole array both positive and negative values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The nice thing about numpy is that you can write things like:

```
 negavg = numpy.mean(windspeed[windspeed < 0.0])
 posavg = numpy.mean(windspeed[windspeed > 0.0])
```

Comment: Note that `mean` is also a method, so you can write `windspeed[windspeed > 0].mean()`.

Comment: Thanks but it returns no array, only one value. And how to get the negative and positive values back in the original state ? but with the corrected values?

Comment: As I understood you wanted to get the average of all negative values inside an array (one number) and the average of all positive values inside the array (one number). This is exactly what the code above delivers. What do you mean with "corrected" values? Please make your request more clear and post example code!